Calculate unique values of par_iter or filter_map?
I want to calculate an embarassingly parallel problem with Rayon, then reduce it to a long stream of maybe a hundred of unique values. It looks like I can't build the hashmap on the fly because mutexes cause deadlocks in Rayon. Because of that, I want to calculate the number of unique values for the iterator I built. Here's a minimal example:
extern crate itertools;
use crate::itertools::Itertools;

extern crate rayon;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let counts_par = (1..=1000000)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|i| i % 10);
    let counts = counts_par.counts();
    println!("{:?}", counts);
}

And the matching Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "elo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
itertools = "0.10.0"

I'm getting the following error:
error[E0599]: the method `counts` exists for struct `Map<Iter<{integer}>, {closure@main.rs:21:14}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:22:29
   |
22 |     let counts = counts_par.counts();
   |                             ^^^^^^
   |
  ::: /home/d33tah/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rayon-1.10.0/src/iter/map.rs:15:1
   |
15 | pub struct Map<I: ParallelIterator, F> {
   | -------------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Iterator` or `_: Itertools`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `rayon::iter::Map<rayon::range_inclusive::Iter<{integer}>, {closure@src/main.rs:21:14: 21:17}>: Iterator`
           which is required by `rayon::iter::Map<rayon::range_inclusive::Iter<{integer}>, {closure@src/main.rs:21:14: 21:17}>: Itertools`
           `&rayon::iter::Map<rayon::range_inclusive::Iter<{integer}>, {closure@src/main.rs:21:14: 21:17}>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&rayon::iter::Map<rayon::range_inclusive::Iter<{integer}>, {closure@src/main.rs:21:14: 21:17}>: Itertools`
           `&mut rayon::iter::Map<rayon::range_inclusive::Iter<{integer}>, {closure@src/main.rs:21:14: 21:17}>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&mut rayon::iter::Map<rayon::range_inclusive::Iter<{integer}>, {closure@src/main.rs:21:14: 21:17}>: Itertools`

How can I solve the problem, assuming that I'm working with a dataset that's too big to fit in the memory?

mutexes cause deadlocks in Rayon - Mutexes cause deadliocks in Rayon if you invoke (even seemingly nurelated) Rayon code while holding the mutex, which results in Rayon running tasks that might end up needing the same mutex, which deadlocks because the mutex is held by code up the stack. While this can and does happen (got bitten by it in production), it doesn't mean that any use of mutex can deadlock Rayon. Locking a mutex, updating a hashmap, and unlocking it is perfectly fine with Rayon. If that weren't the case, Rayon would be almost impossible to use (and even implement).

Just fyi, this is probably not the best way to solve the original problem. Usually you make a separate value for each thread with for_each_with or other similar methods.

You can simply copy and adapt itertools counts implementation for ParallelIterators:
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::hash::Hash;
trait CountsExt: ParallelIterator {
    fn counts(self) -> HashMap<Self::Item, usize>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        Self::Item: Eq + Hash + Sync;
//                           +++++++
}

impl<T: ParallelIterator> CountsExt for T {
    fn counts(self) -> HashMap<Self::Item, usize>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        Self::Item: Eq + Hash + Sync,
//                           +++++++
    {
        let counts = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
        //  ^-mut    +++++++++++              +
        self.for_each(|item| *counts.lock().unwrap().entry(item).or_default() += 1);
        //                          ++++++++++++++++
        counts.into_inner().unwrap()
        //    ++++++++++++++++++++++
    }
}

Playground
